# What is efficient way of updating drupal commerce product prices when your on a product display page?

Tags: 7, commerce

What are some fast ways of updating the product prices for drupal commerce? Right now i have to go into the product list and search for the items I want to change prices on. I know inline entity form solves the issue, but was wondering what other methods are other people doing?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can make a nice edit contextual links with custom_contextual_links module in any view you would like to use this functionality. [image: Custom contextual links example]

Comment: this wont work if you have a select drop down box when selecting item variations. how do you solve that?

Comment: Yeah, I hava a trick for that: You have to add a product_id field first, than add a User field (or Custom field, I don't know exact english translation), label it the way you like, and click in rewrite settings the "Make this field a link" checkbox, next just add a link path like that /admin/commerce/products/[product_id]/edit - you're done!

Comment: do you have a screen shot for that setup? sounds interesting.

Comment: I have changed my answer, see the first screenshot, I hope it's not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use [Commerce backoffice](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module to manage product and order in admin.

> Provides a better experience for stores using nodes as product
>   displays for grouping product variations (commerce_product entities).
>
> - The node/add screen is now split into two tabs, "Create content"       (ordinary node types), and "Create product" (product display node
>     types).
> - The products view is now a view of nodes, showing product       displays. Contains special exposed filters for filtering by product
>     display type, and product display categories.
> - Uses the megarow    pattern to provide a "Quick Edit" link in the    view, that shows all    product variations for that product display,
>     right underneath the    triggering row. The status and price can be
>     modified directly.
> - Modifies the "Content types" screen by adding additional help text       for understanding product displays, and adds a column to the table
>     that indicates whether the node type is a product display node type*.
> - Disables the Commerce-provided "Product types" UI, and provides a       custom "Product variation types" UI that contains additional help
>     text, hides fields that are not used by the Inline Entity Form (help, 
>     description for each type), and provides the ability to create a
>     matching node type for each created product variation type.

It would provide the quick edit product in product display list in admin.